# Magento 2: Can I set a completely custom API endpoint without /rest/V1/?

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I built a custom module with some API endpoints.
For some technical 3rd party requirements, I need to remove the /rest/V1/ from the URLs (only for my module routes).
e.g. - Instead of domain.com/rest/V1/my-endpoint, use domain.com/my-endpoint
Is there a standard way for doing that?

- **I know that I can use controllers & routes instead, but I want to use the API.**
- **.htacces is also not a solution.**

  Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the answer ? @Pini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I just found [this article](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/service-to-web-service.html#configuration-options) on Magento docs which says that the /v1/ is required.
Quote:

> url. Required. String. The URL to the Magento resource. The string must begin with /V1 (or /V) to indicate the version number. You must prepend any template parameters with a colon. Example: /V1/products/:sku

*If someone have found a way to do that anyway, please share your solution. Thanks!